# Как добавить библиотеку json4s в build.sbt файл

Tags: json, intellij-idea, scala

Добрый день.
Начал изучать Scala, нужно написать метод который принимает объект JSON. 
Добавил библиотеку в файл build.sbt вот таким вот образом:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11"
```

Но не вижу что бы она добавилась. Может я что-то пропустил? 
Может нужно как то скомпилировать?

P.S. Работаю в Intellij IDEA первый раз по этому думаю что пропусти какое то действие.

Answer (score 2):

А что-нибудь происходит после сохранения sbt файла? 
Если в Intellij IDEA не стоит настройка auto-import, то нужно обновить проект(зайти в SBT и сделать "Refresh All SBT projects"). После это библиотека должна добавиться.

Answer (score 0):

Надо вот так:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11"
)
```